# Table with unique column+nullable column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem:i have to store a date but
because of only the year can be determined the month and the day are
nullable.The Problem is when i insert a new row with the same year and null for the month and null for the day it will be a duplicate entry

---

`create table date('id' int(10) not null auto_increment,
'Year' int(4) not null,
'Month' int(2) default null,
'Day' int(2) default null,
Primary key('id'),
Unique Key 'Year');`

---

```
insert into date ('id','Year','Month','Day')
```

values (1,1990,NuLL,NULL),
(2,1992,NULL,NULL),
(3,1990,NULL,NULL);

---

Even the unique constraint it will be two entries for 1990 with NULL month and NULL day.

Please help me,i was try to find solution for it but maybe i used the wrong keywords but didn't find.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your unique key to span all three columns, then the only rows that will violate the constraint are those where all three (Day, Month, Year) are non-null and identical.

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

> This constraint does not apply to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.